# How to solve Euler-Lagrange equation using numerical methods?

Tags: numerical-methods, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am attempting to approximate the Euler-Lagrange equation using a numerical solver. I have made the starting steps as follows:

Let $L = f(v, x, t)$ be provided, where $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$.

We assume that the complete numerical 3-dimensional field in $L_{(v, x, t)}$ is provided everywhere.

From the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL}{dv}) = \frac{dL}{dx}\,,$$
a spatial discretization gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta v}) = \frac{L_{(v, x+\Delta x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta x}\,.$$
Then a time discretization gives
$$\frac{(\frac{L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v,x,t+\Delta t)}}{\Delta v}) - (\frac{L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta v})}{\Delta t} = \frac{L_{(v, x+\Delta x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta x}\,.$$
Simplifying,
$$\frac{L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v,x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t)} + L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta v \Delta t} = \frac{L_{(v, x+\Delta x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)}}{\Delta x}$$
$$L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v,x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t)} + L_{(v,x,t)} = \frac{\Delta v \Delta t}{\Delta x}(L_{(v, x+\Delta x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)})$$
$$L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t+\Delta t)} - L_{(v,x,t+\Delta t)}  = \frac{\Delta v \Delta t}{\Delta x}L_{(v, x+\Delta x,t)} - \frac{\Delta v \Delta t}{\Delta x}L_{(v,x,t)} + L_{(v+\Delta v, x,t)} - L_{(v,x,t)} \,.$$

I don't seem to know how to proceed after this step. What is it exactly in the last line above that can be converted into a differential equation (which can then be solved using for instance the Runge-Kutta method)?

Comment: This question is asking to solve and ODE with boundary conditions (or just initial value).

Comment: @RafaelRojas yes i suppose it does, can this be done?

Comment: Yes, any method will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, that's it. You get an implicit equation for $\Delta v$, and then use $\dot x=v$ to get $\Delta x=v\,\Delta t$. Of course, one can also keep the increments for the partial derivatives independent of the actual dynamic increments of the solution. Such a separation might even make more sense if you actually explore multi-dimensional systems where you need multiple difference quotients to evaluate all partial derivatives.

A more balanced approach is to introduce impulses $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}$ which give an implicit equation for $v=\dot x$ and an explicit equation $\dot p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$. Note that in most mechanical systems the Lagrangian is actually separated as $L=T(v)-P(x)$ with the kinetic term $T(v)=\frac{v^TMv}2$ giving an easy relation $p=Mv$, $v=M^{-1}p$. In the next complicated stage you get a semi-mixed $T(x,v)=\frac12v^TM(x)v$ which still gives $v=M(x)^{-1}p$.

Comment: thank you, I have just implemented this by optimizing for $\Delta v$ step-wise, but somehow ended up with a different curve which has a worse $\Sigma L$ than the optimal analytic solution... The problem seems that numerically we could select the best local $\Delta v$ or even $\Delta a$ as our next infinitesimal step in our construction of the cumulative path $s$, but globally the total cost $\Sigma L$  found using local step-wise optimization is overall worse than the analytic solution, which finds the *globally* optimal solution. Could a numerical solver find the globally optimal path $s$?

Comment: This is to be expected. The exact solution is the extremum over all sufficiently smooth functions. The discretization reduces this to a much smaller space, so that one should expect that the functional value is distant from the extremal value. So you get errors from the derivatives approximation and from the integration method, one can improve both, but there will be a lower boundary, at a guess at $\sqrt\mu$ as relative error, $\mu$ being the machine constant. If the function $L$ is not a black-box, you can also do symbolic preparations like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044226